# What is wrong with my logic in for loops - django templates

Tags: django, for-loop, django-templates

This is my `home.html`, problem is with the `if block`:

```
                    {% for menu in menus %}
                      <div class="dropdown show">
                        <a class="btn dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" id="dropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                                        {{ menu.main_menu_item }}
                                      </a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuLink">
                          {% for item in menu.items.all %}
                            {% for second_item in item.items_second_level.all %}
                              {% if item.items_second_level.all != None %}
                                  <li class="dropdown-submenu"><a class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle" href="#">{{ item.sub_menu_item }}</a>
                                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                      <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">{{second_item.sub_menu_item}}</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                  </li>
                              {% else %}
                                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">{{ item.sub_menu_item }}</a></li>
                              {% endif %}
                            {% endfor %}        
                          {% endfor %}
                        </ul>
                      </div>
                    {% endfor %}
```

Namely, `{% else %}` part always "blanks". When I change condition to `{% if item.items_second_level.all == None %}`

again, only items which satisfies the `if condition` get showed (obviously this time the ones that were not shown before). it behaves like there is no `else`. Does anyone know what could be the issue here?

Comment: If there is no items in second lvl there is nothing to iterate on your if condition should be propr to loop

Comment: I literally can't believe I've done this. Thank you!